# Parsing a (possibly non-standard) XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have just started to dive into Python and XML and I am facing a problem of parsing a (possibly) non-standard XML (please correct me if I am wrong).

I want to parse the value of an Element by previously identifying that Element based on the value of its Attribute.

More in details: 
I have two elements `'Name'` and I want to parse the value of the one having Attribute `language == 'en-US'`.

In my XML file, `<'Name' language == 'en-US'>` appears always immediately AFTER `<'Name' language == 'es-ES'>` and I am unable to get the value of the former (e.g. `B`), I can only get the value of the latter (e.g. `A`).

XML file:

```
<Eways>
    <Products>
        <Operator>
            <Name language="es-ES">A</Name>
            <Name language="en-US">B</Name>
        </Operator>
    </Products>
</Eways>
```

Python script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for prod in root.findall('Products'):

    for op in prod.findall('Operator'):
        print op.find('Name').text ### <- Testing, here I would expect to print both A and B, but only A is printed.

        for names in op.iter(tag='Name'):   ### Here I iterate over Element 'Name' trying to get the values anyways.
            l_name = names.get('language')

            if l_name == 'en-US':                     ### My objective is to print out the value of Element 'Name' where Attribute language == en-US.
                print 'OK en-US', names.find('Name')  ### I can not get the values (neither A nor B)
            else:
                print 'KO en-US', names.find('Name')
```

Answer (score 4):

The `element.find()` method only ever finds the *first* matching element. If you expected to find *both* elements, you'd have to use `element.findall()`.

You don't need to do so many loops here; just use an [XPath expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath):

```
for nametag in tree.findall('./Products/Operator/Name[@language]'):
    print nametag.attrib['language'], nametag.text
```

The XPath query is quite specific here; only `Name` elements with a `language` attribute inside an `Operator` inside a `Products` element are found.

The `.text` attribute here gives you the contents.

Demo:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.fromstring('''\
... <Eways>
...     <Products>
...         <Operator>
...             <Name language="es-ES">A</Name>
...             <Name language="en-US">B</Name>
...         </Operator>
...     </Products>
... </Eways>
... ''')
>>> for nametag in tree.findall('./Products/Operator/Name[@language]'):
...     print nametag.attrib['language'], nametag.text
... 
es-ES A
en-US B
```

If you only ever want the `<Name language="en-US">` tags, adjust the XPath query:

```
for nametag in tree.findall("./Products/Operator/Name[@language='en-US']"):
    print nametag.attrib['language'], nametag.text
```

where the `[@language='en-US']` part limits the search to just those tags with a specific attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

The `Name` elements don't themselves contain further elements, so `find` gives `None`. Instead, you just want the `text` of the element:

```
>>> for p in tree.findall("Products"):
    for op in p.findall("Operator"):
        for n in op.findall("Name"):
            print n.get('language'), n.text


es-ES A
en-US B
```

Comment: Thanks to all. Now I got it ;-)